# SPARQL query to get all instances of a wikidata entity including subclasses and ignoring truthiness

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I’m looking for a SPARQL query to extract all instances of a wikidata entity (e.g., countries ([Q6256](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6256)) and any of its subclasses, while ignoring truthiness. My goal is to get all countries (including historic ones) and filter the results later on, if necessary. I also want to use the same query structure for other entities later on (e.g., cities), by swapping out the QID.

I came up with the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?desc WHERE {
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31/p:P279*/ps:P279* wd:Q6256.

  ?item rdfs:label ?desc filter (lang(?desc) = "en").
} ORDER BY ?desc
```

This gets me the direct instances (P31 = instance_of) and those of subclasses (P279 = subclass_of), while ignoring truthiness (by using 'p:/ps:' instead of 'wdt:'). One historic country that was often missing otherwise was [Q16957](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q16957), but this query includes it.

Unfortunately, when I ran the same query for cities ([Q486972](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q486972) = human settlements) I lost ⅔ of the instances compared to using 'wdt:', so something must be wrong and gets missing:

This query returns a count of 2,933,165 ([Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%28COUNT%28%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ486972.%0A%7D)):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q486972.
}
```

While this returns only 981,268 ([Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%28COUNT%28%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fp%3AP279%2a%2Fps%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ486972.%0A%7D)):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31/p:P279*/ps:P279* wd:Q486972.
}
```

So my question is, what would be the correct query/statement to get all instances of a wikidata entity including subclasses and ignoring thruthiness, without losing any potential countries/cities etc.?

Comment: you should switch the `DISTINCT` position as you want to count "distinct items" not get a "distinct count of items" as there is trivially only one count value:   `(COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count)`. That leads to `2 787 904` for the first query, the second one gets a timeout: `SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31/(p:P279/ps:P279)* wd:Q486972.
}` - note, I also made the property path as a repeating sequence pattern `(p:P279/ps:P279)*`

Comment: Thanks, my main issue of missing entities indeed came from using `p:P279*/ps:P279*` instead of `(p:P279/ps:P279)*`. I found that I can also use `(p:P279|ps:P279)*` (does not time out) and do some postprocessing to get what I need.